# How to create a very basic IA with JS?

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence

i want to make a "game", i will try to explain it simply:

- Player Team chooses going to point A or point B
- AI Team Chooses the same (going to A or B)
- Player watches the teams moving (top down view)
- If the teams find themselves then start a battle (just some math and then players instanstly disappear from map when die)
- If not, then AI team goes to Player team's place.

**Optional:**

- Would be nice that if my team is going to A, then before they reach there, suddenly i could make them to move from anywhere to B
- For battles, simulating a vision range would be too difficult?

As you can see, there is almost no gameplay at all, just one choice before the round start, after that it's all simulated. Also the team's units are just circles, so there are not even sprites. I am little experienced with Javascript and i think that it's not very difficult, however i need your help, i don't know what tools do i need to use, Ajax? Maybe a JS framework? Canvas?.

I'm not asking anyone to do the entire script, i'm just asking where to start, what can i do to simulate that movement from teams around the world?.

I would be really thankful if someone could help me, Thanks :)

P.S: Sorry for my english

Comment: Hi, I would use GSAP for the animating: http://greensock.com/gsap

Comment: @Saar wow, those animations are very smooth and the code seems very clear, i will consider GSAP for sure, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use brain.js to train an IA behave like a player and make entries using the new listing property.

This is indeed for a very advanced and almost invincible AI.

You can also make an IA following a premade path for the simpler thing or use edge detection to make a shorter path detection using the edges ans nodes.

Comment: I'm going to check premade paths, it would be perfect since the map ingame never changes. Seems like everything can be achieved with Javascript and some frameworks

Comment: Imho JS is the language for AI